# Does System.Environment.NewLine really allocate 30 bytes of garbage for every call?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity's profiler shows that 30 bytes of garbage are allocated every time I call StringBuilder.AppendLine because it accesses System.Environment.NewLine.

So my questions:

1. Is Unity's profiler giving me the correct information here?
2. Can the value of NewLine actually change at runtime, or is it effectively constant for any given platform?
3. If it can't change, why wouldn't the framework assign the value to a static variable the first time the property is accessed?

Edit: I just used IL spy on Unity's mscorlib.dll and found the source for the property:

```
private static string nl;

...

public static string NewLine
{
    get
    {
        if (Environment.nl != null)
        {
            return Environment.nl;
        }
        Environment.nl = Environment.GetNewLine();
        return Environment.nl;
    }
}

...

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern string GetNewLine();
```

Even if it makes some garbage on the first call, there's no way that should make more every time. It really seems like the profiler is wrong, but it leaves me wondering how that could happen.

Comment: Yeah that's what I originally thought it would be doing, but that doesn't explain why the profiler says it makes garbage.

Comment: Could the 30 bytes simply be the size of the stack frame created in calling `Environment.NewLine`? Does it remain allocated afterward, or is it released?

Comment: The profiler lists it in the "GC Alloc" column, and it goes up by 30 bytes for every call.

Comment: Can you show how you tracked down the fact that the garbage came from the NewLine call?

Comment: Just by using the Unity profiler with Deep Profile turned on. It shows that AppendLine calls Environment.get_NewLine (which allocates 30 bytes per call) and StringBuilder.Append (which allocates nothing and calls String.CharCopy recursively twice, which calls String.memcpy4).